# Get a page token to subscribe my application to the users' pages

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, token, facebook-page

I am developing an application to subscribe to the pages of the users who are authenticated in it.
To test the application I login with a test user (Roles --> Test User)
This test user has two home pages.

Frist, Log in with the user using the facebook login button with this scope:

"Public_profile, email, manage_pages, publish_pages, read_page_mailboxes, pages_show_list, pages_manage_cta, pages_manage_instant_articles"

I grant all this scope and check login status:

```
   FB.getLoginStatus (function (response) {
     If (response.status === 'connected') {
        Console.log (response);
      }
   });
```

All right, response with access_token.

Second Shows the user's pages:

```
   FB.api (
      "/ Me / accounts",
      Function (response) {
        If (response &&! Response.error) {
            Console.log (response);
        }
      }
   ), {Scope: "manage_pages"};
```

And I get the reponse with user's pages perms:

```
  {
    "data":
      [
        {
          "Access_token": "token",
          "Category": "Community",
          "Name": "Procastinators",
          "Id": "1692644001041745",
          "Perms": [
            "ADMINISTER",
            "EDIT_PROFILE",
            "CREATE_CONTENT",
            "MODERATE_CONTENT",
            "CREATE_ADS",
            "BASIC_ADMIN"
          ]
        }],
    Paging
      {
        Cursors
        {"Before": "MTY5MjY0NDAwMTA0MTc0NQZDZD", "after": "MjI5NTU0NjQwODY3NTYz"}
      }
  }
```

And finally i want subscribed (it is necessary page_token, the last call):

````
```

      FB.api (
           "/ 229554640867563 / subscribed_apps",
          Function {response} {
            If (response &&! Response.error) {
              Console.log (response);
            }
          }
      );

```
````

and in this last call to subscribe to the user page, with the page-token  obtained previously fails:

````
```

{
  "error":
  {
    "Message": "(# 210) A page access token is required to request this resource.",
    "Type": "OAuthException",
    "Code": 210,
    "Fbtrace_id": "EVeyT8s \ / Lgz"
  }
}

```
````

If some step is missing help me, I followed these instructions:

1. Login: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web#logindialog
2. Verify status: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web/accesstokens
3. Get Page token https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/access-tokens
4. Subscribed: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/subscribed_apps

All this is in development mode, with test user role.

Thanks for yours time.

Comment: How do you subscribe?

Comment: Using `scope` with `FB.api` makes no sense whatsoever. And you did not use a page token, because otherwise we would see a parameter named `access_token` in your API call.

Comment: I have the `access_token`  to request the `page_token`, but the page_token is **not** returned

Comment: The access_token I was using was not a page_token, I now save the page_access to subscribe.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the token you are using was not the one on the page, so I make sure I use the page token

```
FB.api(
  "/1866825406900964?fields=access_token",
  function(response) {
    if (response && !response.error) {
      page_access_token = response.access_token
      FB.api(
        "/1866825406900964/subscribed_apps?access_token=" + page_access_token,
        function(response) {
          if (response && !response.error) {
            console.log(response);
          }
        }
      );
    }
  }
);
```